# How to convert TimeInterval to CMTime in Swift 4?

Tags: swift

I can’t seem to figure out how to convert TimeInterval to CMTime. Does it need more than just a simple conversion method?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
let timeIntvl: TimeInterval = 60
let cmTime = CMTime(seconds: timeIntvl, preferredTimescale: 1000000)
```

`1000000` represents that the preferred Timescale is 1μsec (1/1000000 sec).

When you convert between some types, there's usually no *simple conversion method* and you may need to find an initializer of the destination type.

[init(seconds: Double, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/cmtime/1489786-init)